# Local push notification in ios for next friday

Tags: ios, timezone, uilocalnotification

I want to set local push notification for next Thursday at 8.00pm.

I have tried but am not able to get on exact time because of some timezone issue.

Please let me know if anybody has idea.

Thanks

Comment: comment this line tuesdayWeek1Notification.timeZone = [NSTimeZone timeZoneForSecondsFromGMT:0];
 and try, hope it helps you

Answer (score 0):

You have to set `notif.timeZone = [NSTimeZone defaultTimeZone];` assuming `notif` is your local notification.

Answer (score 0):

Comment this line

```
tuesdayWeek1Notification.timeZone = [NSTimeZone timeZoneForSecondsFromGMT:0];
```

OR

use this code

```
tuesdayWeek1Notification.timeZone = [NSTimeZone defaultTimeZone];
```

Hope it helps you